# Create an error message if it cannot find the source path

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I've created a class that copies everything in the file and paste it in a different location but I want to be able to add an error message if it cannot find the file path, in case it hasn't been set up on the PC.

I'm using System.IO. So what code would I need to make this check for the file path before actually starting the class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either wrap your code in a try catch, or check if the path exists.

To check if the path exists:

```
    if(Directory.Exists(path)) 
    {
       // logic goes here
    } else 
    {
       // error message
    }
```

Comment: No problem. Check out the msdn, its a great resource: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.exists?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

Here I check the path, and if it doesn't exist, I create it, later I check if a file type txt exist, and I create it too, and write on it. Look this complement, just in case →

```
string path = @"c:\NewFolder";

            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }

            path += @"\Log.txt";

            if (!File.Exists(path))
            {
                var strFile = File.Create(path);
                File.SetAttributes(path, FileAttributes.Normal);
                strFile.Close();
            }

            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path, true))
            {
                string texto = string.Empty;
                texto += "\n Date: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm");
                sw.WriteLine(texto);
                sw.Close();
            }
```